# What is this script on most of the pages I navigate to?

Tags: javascript, html, nodes, tracking, htmlelements

This the code I keep seeing a lot on random pages.

I think it's a google tracking code but could someone confirm?

When I run it in JSFiddle nothing appears to happen.

```js
var tvt = tvt || {};
tvt.captureVariables = function(a) {
  for (var b = new Date, c = {}, d = Object.keys(a || {}), e = 0, f; f = d[e]; e++)
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(f) &&
      "undefined" != typeof a[f]) try {
      var g = [];
      c[f] = JSON.stringify(a[f], function(a, b) {
        try {
          if ("function" !== typeof b) {
            if ("object" === typeof b && null !== b) {
              if (b instanceof HTMLElement || b instanceof Node || -1 != g.indexOf(b)) return;
              g.push(b)
            }
            return b
          }
        } catch (c) {}
      })
    } catch (l) {}
    a = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
  a.initCustomEvent("TvtRetrievedVariablesEvent", !0, !0, {
    variables: c,
    date: b
  });
  window.dispatchEvent(a)
};
window.setTimeout(function() {
  tvt.captureVariables({
    'dataLayer': window['dataLayer']
  })
}, 2000);
```

Comment: This is not any version of google analytics I've ever seen.  It's maybe being injected by a plugin in your browser?  Where are you seeing this?

Comment: If you are seeing this code everywhere, it may be injected by a browser extension. Try loading a page that has it in Incognito Mode (checking that all extensions are disabled)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a script injected by Google's [Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) extension. The source is much larger.

I've unminifed the source code, and it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/okabsd/1b695256155ac7a58ef4) on Gist. Be warned, it is ~6300 lines long - about twenty thousand characters too long for this answer.

The injection occurs around [line 3030](https://gist.github.com/okabsd/1b695256155ac7a58ef4#file-gta-source-js-L3030), with a dynamically created script. Note `kg`, and how they are relying on `Function.prototype.toString` to get the source code of the function.

```js
lg = function(a) {
  if (!a.Ab && (a.Ab = !0, a = a.X(), a = Object.keys(a).map(function(a) {
    return "'" + a + "': window['" + a + "']"
  }), 0 < a.length && (!aa.tvt || !aa.tvt.captureVariables))) {
    var b = document.createElement("script");
    b.textContent = "var tvt = tvt || {}; tvt.captureVariables = " + kg + ";window.setTimeout(function() {tvt.captureVariables({" + a.join(",") + "})}, 2000);";
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(b)
  }
}
```

`kg` can be found [immediately afterwards](https://gist.github.com/okabsd/1b695256155ac7a58ef4#file-gta-source-js-L3035), as the following, which corresponds with what you've posted.

```js
kg = function(a) {
  for (var b = new Date, c = {}, d = Object.keys(a || {}), e = 0, f; f = d[e]; e++)
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(f) &&
      "undefined" != typeof a[f]) try {
      var g = [];
      c[f] = JSON.stringify(a[f], function(a, b) {
        try {
          if ("function" !== typeof b) {
            if ("object" === typeof b && null !== b) {
              if (b instanceof HTMLElement || b instanceof Node || -1 != g.indexOf(b)) return;
              g.push(b)
            }
            return b
          }
        } catch (c) {}
      })
    } catch (l) {}
  a = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
  a.initCustomEvent("TvtRetrievedVariablesEvent", !0, !0, {
    variables: c,
    date: b
  });
  window.dispatchEvent(a)
};
```

A blurb about the extenstion, from [About Tag Assistant](https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/2947093).

> ### About Tag Assistant
>
> Tag Assistant is a Chrome Extension that automatically validates the implementation of Google tracking scripts on any given page. It currently works for:
>
> - Google Analytics (ga.js)
> - Google Analytics (dc.js)
> - AdWords Conversion Tracking
> - AdWords Remarketing (legacy)
> - AdWords Remarketing (new remarketing tag)
> - Doubleclick Floodlight
> - Google Tag Manager
>
> #### How Tag Assistant Works
>
> After installing the extension, you will see an icon indicating the status of the tag on the page you're viewing.
>
> - A grey icon with an 'x' indicates that no code was found on the page
> - A green indicator will show if a valid tag was found. The number in the icon indicates the number of tags that were found
> - A blue indicator will show there are suggestions on improving overall tagging health
> - A yellow indicator will show that a tag was found with minor implementation issues
> - A red indicator will show that a tag was found with critical implementation issues
>
> Click the icon to open a window containing tag details. It shows how many tags were found, how many errors were found, any errors, and a link to the most relevant help document available to resolve the problem. In addition, Tag Assistant makes suggestions when improvements can be made. For example, if an outdated Analytics tag has been installed, Tag Assistant may suggest that you update to a newer tag.

Comment: Chrome must of installed it in my work computer and I forgot about it.... Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

It's just a shortcode for checking if a variable is defined, and if not, defines it as an empty object. It's similar to:

```
if(tvt === undefined){
   tvt = {};
}
```

Basically, it ensures that both:

- the variable is defined (and an object)
- it keeps any previous properties (if any)

---

```js
var obj1 = {prop: 123};
var obj2 = obj1 || {}; // obj2 will have the value of obj1 because obj1 is defined
var obj3 = obj3 || {}; // obj will be an empty object

document.write(JSON.stringify({obj2: obj2, obj3: obj3}));
```

---

*DISCLAIMER: I only answered the first line of the code, because I understood that's what you're asking from the title. But now I see you might be referring to the whole code block. If so, just ignore this answer.*